# Navigate out of icloud drive and into the real world of local storage

Tags: macos, xcode

How do I navigate out of icloud tree in xcode file browser? Somehow the scope of folders to navigate seems to be limited.

I use <kbd>Cmd-K</kbd> to navigate "up" but always end up in the iCloud folder The rest of the navigation options
do not allow to get nowhere near the home directory on local drive where the git repository in question with the project is located.

So how can I access other folders?

[image]

pressing command-k here leads to

[image]

and you are stuck here cause all I have is three stupid icloud folders,
no local drives in sight. Sigh.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your file browser?

Comment: iCloud Drive is an artificial construct, like Recents, so you can't go any higher.

Comment: Exactly, I'm stuck in that artificial construct and can not navigate out of it. That's EXACTLY the problem.

Comment: Now you've added pictures I can see what you did. See new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Open dialog works similar to the Finder, so you can move the mouse on "Favorites" in the left bar to see the "unhide" button, or use <kbd>Cmd-Shift-G</kbd> to enter a path manually.

Answer (score 2):

Switch to Finder, then Cmd/comma for Prefs.
In the Sidebar tab re-enable your local drive locations.

Then, in the file-picker dialog, hover over Favourites & click 'show'.

Alternatively, if you can see the location you need already open on the desktop, you can just drag the icon from the window title bar into your filepicker to go straight there.